# EF DbContext.Set<T> filtered record only ... doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, repository-pattern

While developing a data access solution that utilizes generic repository and unit of work pattern over entity framework 4.2. I am seeing some abnormal behavior. To make my repositories generic, I have utilized the Set method of DbContext like:

```
public class MyGenericRepository<T> 
{
     protected readonly IDbContext context;
     public virtual IEnumerable<T> FindBy(Func<T, bool> predicate)
     {
        return context.GetDbSet<T>().Where(predicate).First();
     }
}
```

where IDbContext is like:

```
public interface IDbContext
{
    void Commit();
    void Attach<T>(T obj) where T : class;
    void Add<T>(T obj) where T : class;
    DbSet<T> GetDbSet<T>() where T : class;
    bool Remove<T>(T item) where T : class;
}
```

The DbContext class implements the IDbContext as:

```
public partial class MyEntities : IDbContext
{

    public DbSet<T> GetDbSet<T>() where T : class
    {
        return this.Set<T>();
    }
}
```

When I do repository.FindBy(c => c.CompanyId == 45), Sql Profiler shows the query to **NOT** contain any filter (company_id = 45). The query does a Select *.

Expecting a filter to be present, i started researching and came across this,

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/7d6705ac-f875-4c89-960b-842be6f6e5ed
and 
[EF DbContext.Set<T> filtered record only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362145/ef-dbcontext-sett-filtered-record-only)

These threads confirms my thought process but the results are different. Any solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your predicate is a `Func<T, bool>`, which forces the query to use the `Enumerable.Where` method instead of the `Queryable.Where` method.

Change the predicate to `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` and everything should start working.